# The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: dart

Dart as you can see in the below php code.i am trig to crater variable name "token" of  **getTokenValue()**and use into token**addSingleProduct(productInfo,token,callback)**int thi function as String but i can't use

```
Future <String> getTokenValue()async{
 final  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 final String token=sharedPreferences.getString('token');
 print("accept token : ${token}");
  return token;
}
 final token= getTokenValue();

onPressed: (){
                  addSingleProduct(productInfo,token,callback);   //"token"  The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
                },
```

Comment: You should "await" the getTokenValue() call:
 final token= await getTokenValue();

Answer (score 0):

You have to await until you get the string value. So call the function inside button press call

```
onPressed: ()async{
    String token = await getTokenValue();
    addSingleProduct(productInfo,token,callback);
         }
```

Hope this fix your issue.